# Compute approximately the probability that more than 50 of the observations of the random sample are less than 3.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n = 72$ from a distribution
with probability density function

$f(x) =\begin{cases} 1/x^2,& 1 < x < infinity\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Compute approximately the probability that more than $50$ of the ob-
servations of the random sample are less than $3$.

Comment: Compute approximately the probability that more than 50 of the ob-
servations of the random sample are less than 3.

Comment: Welcome to the website! What are your thoughts on this problem, where are you stuck? Where did you get it? Can you add this information to the question?

Comment: its an assingment i got from school, and im failing to compute the answer

Comment: you could start by looking at the probability a particular observation is less than 3

Comment: i'm still struggling to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step I :

Define $Z_i = I_{\{X_i < 3\}}$ and find the probability that $Z_i = 1$ which is equal to $\int_{1}^{3}{f(x)dx}$.

Step II :

Apply Central Limit Theorem on $Z_i$'s to approximate $P[\sum_{i=1}^{72}{Z_i} > 50]$. If you do not know how to do that, here is a reference for the same (page 6) [https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter9.pdf](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Echance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter9.pdf)

Comment: i got stuck at the central limit theorem

Comment: Could you come up with the values of $n, p, q$ for this problem to apply CLT ?

Comment: i am clueless with this question, how have you solved it please

Comment: $n=72$ here and $p$ is the integral you solved in Step I and $q=1-p$. If you use these values in the formula given in page 8 of the pdf I referred to(just above example 9.2). You would get the answer. You also need to substitute $i=51$ and $j=72$ in that formula.

Comment: thank you, i found -1/3 in the integral solved in step 1, so when i plug it in the formula under the square root it becomes undifined, so im still stuck , how did you solve

Comment: minor change in my answer, the limits are from $1$ to $3$ not $0$ to $3$...so the integral evaluates to $\frac{2}{3}$. Therefore, $p=2/3$ and $q=1/3$

Comment: i found p=2/3 , q=1/3, n=72, then substituted i=51 and j=72.... plugged into the formula and i got P(5/8, 49/8) . I know if i misculculated , is this what you got ? where did i go wrong

Comment: Yup, that looks correct.

Comment: alright so this is the probability that more than 50 of the observations of the random sample are less than 3 ?

Comment: You need to compute that P(5/8, 49/8) though using a normal probability table..Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: im not sure about the table, im a little rusty.. help out

Comment: For now you can use this website http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html ...select between and enter the values in decimal (not fraction) it will compute the probability for you

Comment: thank you very much for your exceptional help ..i managed to get 0.2266

Comment: It should be 0.266

Comment: sorry i meant to say 0.266.  thank you